# Conditional not evaluating as expected

Tags: conditionals

I have this conditional

```
{if '{logged_in_group_id}' == '{exp:config_variables:get name="xxxxx"}'}...
```

where `{logged_in_group_id}` is equal to 3

and `{exp:config_variables:get name="xxxxx"}` is equal to 3

But why does this conditional return false?

I have also tried using a literal value

{if '{logged_in_group_id}' == '3'}...
{if '3' == '{exp:config_variables:get name="xxxxx"}'}...

but they still returned false.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: How does it work if you use something like Mo Variables to make logged_in_group_id an early parsed variable? http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is parse order, and there may be several workarounds for that... however, (and I'm guessing a bit at what you're trying to do) I would suggest that instead of using this unusual exp:config_variables add-on and faffing about with parse order that you use the `assign_to_config` array to create your own early-parsed global variables. Then you can do a nice clean:

`{if logged_in_group_id == {gv_special-group-id}}...{/if}`

You can achieve this as documented either in the main index.php file, or if you prefer with a little trickery you can do it in your config.php file [like this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/how-to-create-a-global-variable-inside-config-php).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without using quotes around the variables?

For example, instead of '{logged_in_group}' you should just say {logged_in_group}

If you use quotes, I believe you are actually comparing strings, instead of comparing the values, and that means you are literally comparing the string {logged_in_group} to 3 instead of getting the value and comparing the two integers.

Comment: I tried it without quotes and even without the curly braces. It still evaluated the conditional wrong.

Comment: I assume you probably have, but have you output the contents of those variables to ensure they are actually returning the integer 3 as expected?

Comment: Yes, I have and they are exactly what I expected

Comment: I gave a vote to the answer from James, as I feel parse order makes sense as the likely culprit then.