# Detecting Server Environment in Template - {site_url} Conditional Fails

Tags: templates, conditionals, site-url

Problem: Include analytic JS code in production, but not in staging or development.

Attempted to detect production environment with:

`{if "{site_url}" == "http://www.example.com/"}`

... but that's not evaluating as true; attempted to debug to get correct value of `{site_url}`, but, the value I'm using looks to be correct (copied/pasted to be sure).

`<!-- {site_url} -->` outputs `<!-- http://www.example.com/ -->`

Is this a parse order issue, or is there sometime obvious I'm missing in my pre-coffee state this morning?

If it's parse order, how do you go about doing conditionals on the environment within your templates if not with `{site_url}`?

Note: I'll actually respond if you take the time to assist, and, I'll mark the correct answer as answered ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or set a $env_global['myjs'] in the config.prod.php with the analytics code ID number and leave that var blank in the config.dev.php then just {myjs} in the template and it only outputs the ID in production.

Comment: Interesting; have been doing this a long time, didn't know about `$env_global`s; thanks!

Comment: Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction! For future reference to anyone else who might stumble across this, the concept is fleshed out in more detail here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/

Answer (score 0):

{if site_url == "www.example.com"} it's true! {/if}

I think your syntax is incorrect. Notice that the site variable does not have {} or uses quotes. That's no correct in the EE syntax.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html

Comment: Tried with and without quotes, made no difference.